# Upgrading Visual studio 2008 Professional to Visual studio 2010 Premium

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, upgrade

I currently have Visual Studio 2008 Professional installed on my Windows 7 (x64) laptop.
I also have SQL Server 2008 Express and Crystal Reports 2008 installed.

Can I upgrade Visual Studio 2008 Pro to Visual Studio 2010 Premium and if so do I have to make any configuration changes to any other apps I have installed?

Comment: Visual Studio "Preimum" and "Promimum".  "laaptop"?  I prey to the SO gods that I will accidentally be granted edit privileges to non-community wiki posts :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, you cannot "upgrade" Visual Studio in the traditional sense. Visual Studio exists side-by-side (sxs) with older versions, so you have *both* versions installed. What does get upgraded is the CSPROJ (or VBPROJ) files that represent your projects.

Comment: What about SQL Server and Crystal Reports. Do I have to do anything with these applications?

Answer (score 2):

It's a side-by-side install, you can continue to use both installations for development.  As for other two:

Your SQL Server will continue to work for both VS2008 and VS2010, [SP1 adds the .Net 4 support](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/12/09/sql-server-express-and-net-4.aspx).

Crystal Reports will not...however there is a new 2010 version, just not included in the base Visual Studio install anymore.  It will be available as a separate (still **free**) download from SAP.  It's currently in beta 2 status (as of the time of this answer) but should be released sometime soon.  SAP updates the current status at this blog here so you can keep track:
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/14514

Comment: I remember having 2 visual studios installed, and it was totally painful for my Windows