# Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

I am going to upgrade Visual Studio 2008 Professional to Visual Studio 2010 Preimum.

I also have Crystal Reports 2008 installed.

Will Crystal Reports cause any problems? And will Visual Studio 2010 Preimum recognize my Crystal Reports install alllowing usage of Crystall Reports 2008 in my applications?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706899/upgrading-visual-studio-2008-professional-to-visual-studio-2010-preimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing VS2010 doesn't necessarily change your VS2008 install whatsoever. I have VS2010 Ultimate installed side-by-side with VS2008 and have had zero problems with Crystal Reports when I load those projects in VS2008.

I would not recommend getting rid of VS2008 right away as there is no embedded Crystal Reports in VS2010 and the new runtime download seems to be in beta. I'd try out the separate download offered by SAP and ensure everything works in your environment. Their blog has all the details:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/14514