# I have vs.net 2008 professional, is there a upgrade to 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading Visual studio 2008 Professional to Visual studio 2010 Premium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706899/upgrading-visual-studio-2008-professional-to-visual-studio-2010-premium)

Is there a upgrade from 2008 professional to 2010?

Hoping it doesn't cost too much!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no upgrade option.

Partially because they are designed to run side by side (as with VS 2005).

You will need to get a VS 2010 license and pay full price for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a product you can buy that upgrades 2008 to 2010 for less than the cost of 2010 Pro. I'm afraid the answer is no.